# Какой порождающий шаблон проектирования использовать?

Tags: c#, архитектура, шаблоны-проектирования, рефакторинг, чистый-код

Есть два класса с многими по бизнесу общими полями, и с парой специфичных:

```cs
class ClassA {
    public int Field1 {get;set;} // общее поле 1
    //...
    public int FieldN {get;set;} // общее поле N
    public int SpecificA {get;set;} // специфичное поле для A
}
class ClassB {
    public int Field1 {get;set;} // общее поле 1
    //...
    public int FieldN {get;set;} // общее поле N
    public int SpecificB {get;set;} // специфичное поле для B
}
```

Я думаю создать для них общий класс `BaseClass`:

```cs
class BaseClass {
    public int Field1 {get;set;} // общее поле 1
    // ...
    public int FieldN {get;set;} // общее поле N
}
// И убрать из ClassA и ClassB общие поля в него, оставив только специфичные:
class ClassA : BaseClass {
    public int SpecificA {get;set;} // специфичное поле для A
}
class ClassB : BaseClass {
    public int SpecificB {get;set;} // специфичное поле для B
}
```

И создать такую фабрику(не уверен, что этот термин подходит):

```cs
public class Factory {
    public static ClassA CreateClassA(){
        var classA = new ClassA();
        // Заполняем поля общие с классом ClassB
        UpdateGeneralFields(classA);
        // Заполняем специфичные для ClassA поля
        classA.SpecificA = 'specificA';
        return classA;
    }
    public static ClassB CreateClassB(){ 
        var classB = new ClassB();
        // Заполняем поля общие с классом ClassB
        UpdateGeneralFields(classB);
        // Заполняем специфичные для ClassB поля
        classB.SpecificB = 'specificB';
        return classB;
    }

    private static void UpdateGeneralFields(BaseClass baseClass){
        baseClass.Field1 = 1;
        // ...
        baseClass.FieldN = N;
    }
}
```

**Вопросы**

1. Это правильный подход?
2. Как можно создавать такие типы объектов используя известные порождающие шаблоны проектирования?
3. Насколько такой код может считаться чистым?
4. Что тут можно улучшить?

Comment: У вас никакие свойства создаваемых объектов не зависят от аргументов. Так и задумано? Так и останется?

Comment: Если не планируется полиморфизм типа `IEnumerable<BaseClass>` или что-то подобное, то лучше использовать композицию вместо наследования. Повторяющиеся свойства - это не причина для наследования.

Comment: @Kyubey аргументы опущены для простоты

Comment: зачем _UpdateGeneralFields_ если это можно сделать в конструкторе базового класса. А специфичный поля - в конструкторах конкретных классов, в итоге методы `CreateClass*`  вырождаются в простой вызов конструктора конкретного класса

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov Убрав аргументы, вы выкинули ключевую часть требований к коду. Очень много дублирования будет именно в аргументах.

Comment: @Grundy , а у меня одна из специфичных моделей требует асинхронный вызов сервиса что бы себя сделать, и я ей передаю сервис для вызова.

Comment: @Kyubey , там по два параметра передаются в тот и другой.

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov, значит для этой модели будет вызов

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov Если необходимо одинаково обращаться к разным экземплярам разных классов по общим полям, то лучший выход, на мой взгляд - `Interface`. Взгляните в мои вопросы, там есть вполне полный пример этого.

Comment: @Grundy в итоге сделал инициализацию через конструкторы как вы предложили. Можете сделать ответ.

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov, если у тебя получилось решить свою задачу, можешь сам ответить на свой вопрос с описанием как решал

Answer (score -1):

Наследование стоит использовать только при наличии логики - является. А повторение свойств вовсе не причина для наследования, как было уже сказано выше. И, Является совершенно не видно. Впрочем, это как я понимаю упрощение, в реале, все будет зависеть от контекста.

Comment: в настоящем примере, не синтетическом как в вопросе присутсвует отношение "является". Там собирается вью модель для передачи через rest. Модель характеристик документа, и в двух разных случаях надо чуть разные поля передавать но очень много общих полей.